# How to make/transform existing directory into git submodule?

Tags: git, refactoring, project, git-submodules

So I'm having this project where some parts have been developed in the main repo but can be moved to an independently developed sub-module :

```
./                       ← repo root
├── client-angular/
│   └── whatever/
├── resources/
│   └── script/          ← wanna be sub-module
└── server-codeigniter/
```

#### Question

How can I make the `script/` directory into a git submodule with minimal effort ?
 It is **currently tracked** by the main repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Answer (score 2):

Once you have extracted the sub-folder in its own repo (as explained in "[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295550/6309)"), you will still have to:

- push that new repo on a remote server (GitHub for instance)
- `git rm -r resources/script`
- and add the remote new repo as a submodule

  ```
  git submodule add /url/new/repo resources/scripts
  ```